# Is it normal to have 2 packages in npm? Trying to install angular cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I typed in "sudo npm install npm -g". I was following the instructions in the video at this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node. As you can see that it was stated at the bottom that 2 packages was updated. Is this normal? What should I do?

[image]

Also, since I was trying to install angular cli, I typed in "npm install -g @angular/cli" but the terminal on my mac was stuck in a loop so I had to terminate it. So I thought that I may have to start over again. So I typed in "sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli", but I got this result:
[image]

The warning said that the npm doesn't support Node.js v9.2.0. I can't understand this since I did try to update by following the video above. So does it have to do with the two packages I mentioned above?

Comment: The NPM package `angular-cli` was renamed to `@angular/cli` in line with the other Angular packages.

Answer (score 0):

it normally has package.json but sometimes package-lock.json is auto generated too. So, after finishing installing, it might be referring to updating the two packages. Here is a helpful link to clarify package-lock.json - https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Comment: It basically says that package-lock.json is used as a version management of the node modules.  The package.json is where all the dependencies are stored. So, its okay to have them both and when you install a new module both of them will be updated.